# Are Spider-Man & Deadpool the only characters who have met alternate versions of themselves?

Tags: marvel

As I understand it, Spider-Man has met alternative versions of himself on several different instances, such as the Noir, 2099, & Ultimate alternates, at one point teaming up with them and other alternates as Web- Warriors. Deadpool also has encountered several alternate versions of himself, going so far as to create an entire team of alternate Deadpools known as the Deadpool Corps. I was just curious: have any of the other Marvel characters experienced similar encounters, or has it only been Spidey and the lovable Merc with the Mouth?

Comment: It gets tricky distinguishing between "alternate versions" and time travel, especially when the timeline changes.  Thor went on adventure with his younger and older selves, for example.  Would that qualify?

Comment: I haven't read much of Secret War but wouldn't lots of these characters be meeting once -616 and -1610 start fighting?

Comment: Is there any character who **hasn't** met an evil version of him/herself from an alternate universe?

Comment: From your comments on people's answers I can tell that you have some specific criteria in mind for what "alternate versions of themselves" means, and I *think* I see what you're trying to get at. Could you edit your question to clarify those criteria?

Comment: The numerous and varied answers here are exactly why I hate "do any exist" questions.

Comment: @phantom42 so more annoying stuff over there to hate over, let these ones slip...

Comment: I think it all started when the Silver Age Flash encountered the Golden Age version of himself.

Comment: Funny how a simple "yes/no" question turned out as "too broad". Q: `have any of the other Marvel characters experienced similar encounters, or has it only been Spidey and the lovable Merc with the Mouth?` A: `yes.`

Comment: @Mindwin Yes, that's historically the problem with such questions. Simply saying "yes" without providing examples is a valid, but poor answer - exactly the type of answer we typically try to discourage. It becomes problematic here because as all of these examples are "correct", meaning no answer is really more correct than another, so no one answer can be objectively declared as "correct". These *are* often good/interesting questions, but poor fits for the main site.

Answer (score 11):

Characters meeting alternate versions of themselves is a common trope in Marvel comics. There are too many instances of this to list, but here are a few:

- The [**Hulk**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulk_(comics)) most famously fought a future version of himself ([Maestro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maestro_(comics))) in the [The Incredible Hulk: Future Imperfect](http://marvel.wikia.com/Incredible_Hulk:_Future_Imperfect_Vol_1_1) series. The Maestro character would later appear several other times as well, always posing a dangerous threat to the younger Hulk.
- If you count the psychic plane, the various incarnations of The Hulk had to face a new incarnation - Guilt Hulk - within Bruce Banner's mind in [Incredible Hulk #377](http://marvel.wikia.com/Incredible_Hulk_Vol_1_377). The Guilt Hulk, an evil persona based on Bruce's abusive father, would show up again later as well.
- The original five [**X-Men**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men) were brought forward into the future in the [All-New X-Men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-New_X-Men) series, resulting in all but [Jean Grey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Grey) meeting themselves. This proved particularly traumatic for [Scott Summers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclops_(comics)), who ended up fighting his older self on several occasions.
- An offshoot of the Exiles, the [**Wolverine Squad**](http://marvel.wikia.com/Exiles_Vol_1_85) is a team made up entirely of Wolverines from different universes. The team was created specifically to kill a gestalt being - [Brother Mutant](http://marvel.wikia.com/Brother_Mutant_(Earth-127)) - which included yet ANOTHER version of Wolverine in its makeup.
- The current "[Secret Wars](http://marvel.wikia.com/Secret_Wars)" arc witnessed multiple characters meeting alternate versions of themselves
- In the [new reality](http://marvel.wikia.com/Battleworld_(Latverion)) ruled over by Doom, his will is enforced by [**The Thor Corps**](http://marvel.wikia.com/Doomgard) - a police force comprised entirely of Thors from different universes.
- The [**X-Termination**](http://marvel.wikia.com/X-Termination) event saw X-Men from three different continuities interact.

These are just a few - there are numerous examples available. And if you count cases where the doppelganger is an android, clone, shape-shifter, or something else assuming the form of a character, the list becomes even larger.

Comment: ...and also Bizzaro.

Comment: @Daft: yes, LOL, the expanded list would indeed include characters like Bizarro.

Answer (score 6):

The Ultimate Fantastic Four had the unfortunate luck to meet their Zombie-Universe counterparts in [Ultimate Fantastic Four Vol. 1, issue 21.](http://marvel.wikia.com/Ultimate_Fantastic_Four_Vol_1_21)

[image]

This was the beginning of the Marvel Zombies storylines. I'm certain there are other instances of Marvel characters meeting other-universe counterparts, but this one sticks out in my mind.

Comment: Only answer so far that seems to apply.

Answer (score 5):

Here are three panels from Alan Moore's run on Captain Britain in which the hero meets numerous alternative versions of himself.
[image: Captain Britain and alternative versions]

There was later an entire superhero team formed of alternative versions of Captain Britain, the [Captain Britain Corps](http://www.comicvine.com/captain-britain-corps/4060-23438/).

Comment: I like this answer, but are these actually different versions of Brian Braddock? I thought they were different people filling the "Captain Britain" role.

Comment: It depends what the original question meant by "alternative versions of himself". They're alternative versions of Captain Britain, but not of Brian Braddock.

Answer (score 3):

Not if you include Beta Ray Bill/Beta Ray Thor as an alternate version of Thor:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thor has also met this alternate version of himself:

[image]

And he once turned into a Hulked-Out version of himself:

[image]

And as cde pointed out, in Thor Corps, Thor teamed up with Beta Ray Bill, Thunderstrike, and Thor 2099.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is just different characters in the same role, though. If we count Thor & Beta Ray Bill, we'd also have to include Green Hulk/Red Hulk or different team rosters (Old Avengers vs. New Avengers).

Comment: Your middle example is a good one, btw.

Comment: Op included Spiderman 2099. Thor has also met Thor 2099.

Comment: @cde - I didn't know that.  I can't find any pictures of it, or I'd add them.

Comment: Thor corps. Thor, Thorse, Thunder Strike and Dargo Ktor Thor 2099 team up.

Comment: @cde - Many thanks.  Added.

Answer (score 1):

Xmen travel through alternative time lines like squirrels cross branches of a tree.

Cable has met Nate Grey the X Man, and Strife.

Beast was kidnapped and tortured by Dark Beast.

Gambit fought Sun, a physical god version of himself.

Storm and Wolverine have met their days of future past punk counterparts.

Wolverine has met I think, his gay and in love with Hercules alternative self.

SheHulk has met and interrogated her "Slept with Juggernaut" copy.

Comment: _a physical god version of himself_... imagine pitching that idea.

Comment: There's a gay version of Wolverine? That's the most evil thing I can think of. It's like picturing Clint Eastwood in drag.

Comment: @omega And he has a Freddy mercury mustache to boot

Comment: Wasn't Stryfe Cable's son?

Comment: @mindwin Cables clone, and the real father to cables son.

Comment: @cde Funny family and their clones, always siring the next generation in lieu of the real person.

Answer (score 0):

The X-man met the X-babies, alternate versions of themselves created by Mojo.

Jean Grey and Madeline Pryor.

Magneto and Joseph